# How do i display 'some text' if i user is Loged in then duration column

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, asp.net-mvc-5.2

How do i display 'some text' if i am using log-in log-out application if i am in Loged-In then in duration column should show "Working" and after log-out total log-in and log-out time using  kendo Grid.

This is My Code.

```
columns.Bound(c => c.Duration).Groupable(false).Filterable(false)
               .ClientGroupFooterTemplate("#= time.minutesToTime(data.DurationInMinutes.sum) # ")
               .ClientFooterTemplate("#= time.minutesToTime(data.DurationInMinutes.sum) # ")
               .ClientTemplate("#=typeof Duration!='undefined'?formatDuration(Duration.Hours,Duration.Minutes):0#").HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "" });
```

[image: This is The Image where i did]

Comment: Do it in the `ClientTemplate`. You should have something to point that the user is logged in, so use a simple condition to show the text.

Comment: Do you have a field in your result set to indicate if the user is currently logged in?

Answer (score 0):

I Tried like this in my code then i am getting my result.

```
columns.Bound(c => c.Duration).Groupable(false).Filterable(false)
               .ClientGroupFooterTemplate("#= time.minutesToTime(data.DurationInMinutes.sum) # ")
               .ClientFooterTemplate("#= time.minutesToTime(data.DurationInMinutes.sum) # ")            
               .ClientTemplate("#=typeof Duration!= 'undefined' && ClockOut !== null ? formatDuration(Duration.Hours,Duration.Minutes): 'Working' #")
               .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "" });
```